# Spring ResponseErrorHandler without parsing objects

Tags: java, spring, http, resttemplate

I am using SpringBoot with `RestTemplate` to communicate with another application. However, I am unable to change its API and this external service always Returns `200OK` return code.

By Default, we have `ResponseErrorHandler` that reacts to all `4xx` and `5xx` response codes but in my case when there is an exception I get `200OK` with one JSON field `errors`.

I have created a custom error handler and bundled it into my rest template by using:

```
restTemplate.errorHandler(new MyCustomErrorHandler());
```

I have also overrided `hasError()` method but inside I have to parse this object to check whether it contains fields with errors...

Is this a good approach for error handling? Should I parse response twice? I seek for the clean solution for such problems but I want to avoid parsing message twice every time I use external service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error handler will only be invoked if an error state is returned, 200 is not an error state so it is not handled.

You can change this behavior by overriding hasError method ResponseErrorHandler to check for error message or any indication for error.

```
public class MyCustomErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

@Override
public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse) 
        throws IOException {

    //TODO check your criteria for error
}
```

Comment: I did exacly that, but inside hasError I have to parse whole response to Json Object in order to check for error fields. I have forgot to mention that. Thanks for pointing that out.